# Understanding a variable and arithmetic operator in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand what the `NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=$((${2} - 1))` specifically `- 1` does in this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copyright © 2017 Google Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

IFS=$'\n\t'
set -eou pipefail

if [[ "$#" -ne 2 || "${1}" == '-h' || "${1}" == '--help' ]]; then
    cat >&2 <<"EOF"
housekeeping_images.sh cleans up tagged or untagged images pushed for a given repository (an image name without a tag/digest)
and except the given number most recent images
USAGE:
  housekeeping_images.sh REPOSITORY NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN
EXAMPLE
  housekeeping_images.sh eu.gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/IMAGE_NAME 5
  would clean up everything under the eu.gcr.io/test-project/php repository
  pushed except for the 5 most recent images
EOF
    exit 1
# elif [ ${2} -ge 0 ] 2>/dev/null; then
#     echo "no number of images to remain given" >&2
#     exit 1
fi

main() {
    local C=0
    IMAGE="${1}"
    NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=$((${2} - 1))

    DATE=$(gcloud container images list-tags $IMAGE --limit=unlimited \
        --sort-by=~TIMESTAMP --format=json | TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC jq -r '.['$NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN'].timestamp.datetime | sub("(?<before>.*):"; .before ) | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z") | mktime | strftime("%Y-%m-%d")')

    for digest in $(gcloud container images list-tags $IMAGE --limit=unlimited --sort-by=~TIMESTAMP \
        --filter="timestamp.datetime < '${DATE}'" --format='get(digest)'); do
        (
            set -x
            gcloud container images delete -q --force-delete-tags "${IMAGE}@${digest}"
        )
        let C=C+1
    done
    echo "Deleted ${C} images in ${IMAGE}." >&2
}

main "${1}" ${2}
```

Comment: It subtracts 1, just like in grade school arithmetic.

Comment: `$2` is the second positional parameter (second argument to the function) `$(...)` is the arithmetic operator's result. So `$((${2} - 1))` subtracts `1` from the 2nd function argument assigning the value to `NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN` `( ... )` is the arithmetic operator alone. The additional set of parenthesis inside `$( ... )` are unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: It's inside a function, so it's not a command line argument, but the function's argument.

Comment: @choroba - good catch.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is what I thought too, but if I change this number to anything besides 1, it does not work correctly. For example, if I set - 1 to - 3, and then run ./script eu.gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/IMAGE_NAME" 4 it only deletes two images

Comment: It will very much depend on what `"$2"` to the function is. For example, the (rather unnecessary) `main()` function simply takes the first two command line arguments to the script. So whatever `"$2"` is, it must be larger than whatever number you choose, otherwise the number of images that remain would be negative. (side note, don't use `ALLCAPS` variable names, those are generally reserved for system variables, lowercase is fine)

Comment: You must run `./script eu.gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/IMAGE_NAME" 4 X` where `X` is a second number that will become `"$2"`. By just giving one parameter `4`, `"$2"` will be `0` and you will have negative images remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example from the script's comments:

```
housekeeping_images.sh eu.gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/IMAGE_NAME 5
```

The last line in the script:

```
main "${1}" ${2}
```

becomes:

```
main "eu.gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/IMAGE_NAME" 5
```

Inside the `main()` function the variable assignments:

```
IMAGE="${1}"
NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=$((${2} - 1))
```

become:

```
IMAGE="eu.gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/IMAGE_NAME"
NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=$((5 - 1))
```

with the 2nd variable receiving the final value:

```
NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=4
```

Comment: That is what I would have thought too, but if I change this number to anything besides 1, it does not work correctly.

For example, if I set `- 1` to `- 3`, and then run `./script eu.gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/IMAGE_NAME" 4` it only deletes two images.

Comment: keep in mind the script is supposed to delete all *EXCEPT* the last `NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=5` image files; if you had 6 files and you pass in `NUMBER_OF_IMAGES_TO_REMAIN=4` then I'd expect only 2 files to be removed, and 4 files to remain:  **NOTE:** I haven't reviewed the actual logic in the script, at this point I'm assuming it works as stated in the documentation

Comment: ugh :facepalm: Yep, thank you. That is what was messing me up. Thank you so much!